# Losing data when refresh RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have two `List<>` instances, I clear both lists then my data is lost. I clear it using this code:

```
private List<ContentProfileDashboard> contentListDashboard;
private AdapterProfileDashboard adapterProfileDashboard;
private ContentProfileDashboard contentProfileDashboard;
....

// button in MainFragment not in Adapter
buttonRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // this is first list that i clear
        contentListDashboard.clear();
        // this is second list that i clear from Adapter class List<ContentProfileDashboard> contentList;
        adapterProfileDashboard.contentList.clear();

        contentListDashboard.add(contentProfileDashboard);
        adapterProfileDashboard.notifyDataSetChanged();    

    }
});
```

This is MainFragment named **ProfileFragment.class**

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    //private RecyclerView recyclerSeen;
    private RecyclerView recyclerProfileDashboard;
    //private List<ContentProfile> contentList;
    private List<ContentProfileDashboard> contentListDashboard;
    //private AdapterSeenProfileDashboard adapterSeen;
    private AdapterProfileDashboard adapterProfileDashboard;
    private Boolean isFirstPageFirstLoad = true;
    //private ContentProfile contentSeen;
    private ContentProfileDashboard contentProfileDashboard;

    private Boolean allowRefresh = true;
    private CircleImageView profileImage;
    private CircleImageView profileStatusImage;

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private DocumentSnapshot lastVisible;
    private View view;

    private TextView profileNickName;
    private TextView profileLongName;
    private TextView profileStatusIsActive;
    private Button buttonRefresh;

    private int currentItems, totalItems, scrollOutItems;
    private LinearLayoutManager manager;
    private Boolean isScrolling = false;

    public ProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        //firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbarProfile);
        // toolbar.setTitle("Rashid");

        profileImage = view.findViewById(R.id.circleImageProfile);
        profileNickName = view.findViewById(R.id.nick_name);
        profileLongName = view.findViewById(R.id.long_name);
        profileStatusIsActive = view.findViewById(R.id.status_active);
        profileStatusImage = view.findViewById(R.id.circleImageStatus);
        profilePosition = view.findViewById(R.id.position_in_company);

        //for crate home button
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        //MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity(); // MainActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            if (activity.getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); // back button
                activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
                activity.getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.googleg_disabled_color_18);
                activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
            }
        }

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        //contentList = new ArrayList<>();
        contentListDashboard = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerProfileDashboard = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_dashboard_profile);

        //horizontal
        //recyclerSeen = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_seenBy);

        //adapterSeen = new AdapterSeenProfileDashboard(contentList);
        adapterProfileDashboard = new AdapterProfileDashboard(contentListDashboard);

        //vertical
//        recyclerSeen = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_dashboard_profile);
//        recyclerSeen.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext()));

        manager = new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext());
        recyclerProfileDashboard.setLayoutManager(manager);

        //horizontal
        //recyclerSeen.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

        // vertical
        //recyclerSeen.setAdapter(adapterSeen);
        recyclerProfileDashboard.setAdapter(adapterProfileDashboard);

        profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {             


                // Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Register.class);             
                // startActivity(intent); // make sr crash from DesignIn not from intent

                contentListDashboard.add(contentProfileDashboard);
                adapterProfileDashboard.update(contentListDashboard);

            }
        });

        // CHECK 2
        buttonRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                contentListDashboard.clear();
                adapterProfileDashboard.contentList.clear();
                contentListDashboard.add(contentProfileDashboard);
                adapterProfileDashboard.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });

        // CHECK 2
        profileLongName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                adapterProfileDashboard.contentList.clear();
                adapterProfileDashboard.contentList.addAll(contentListDashboard);
                adapterProfileDashboard.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        loadFirstQuery();
    }


    public void loadFirstQuery() {


        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

            contentListDashboard.clear();

            String currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                    firebaseFirestore
                    .collection("ProfileDashboard")
                    .document(currentUserId)
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                if (task.getResult() != null) {
                                    String image = task.getResult().getString("image");
                                    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
                                    requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profile_off);
                                    Glide.with(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).applyDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions).load(image).into(profileImage);

                                    String nickName = task.getResult().getString("nickName");
                                    profileNickName.setText(nickName);

                                    String longName = task.getResult().getString("longName");
                                    profileLongName.setText(longName);

                                    String status = task.getResult().getString("status");

                                    if (status != null) {
                                        if (status.equals("ACTIVE")){
                                            profileStatusIsActive.setText(status);
                                            profileStatusImage.setImageResource(R.color.colorAccent);
                                        } else {
                                            profileStatusIsActive.setText(status);
                                            profileStatusImage.setImageResource(R.color.darkGrey);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    String position = task.getResult().getString("position");
                                    profilePosition.setText(position);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });


            // recyclerProfileDashboard.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            //    @Override
            //    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            //        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            //        // horizontal
            //        //Boolean reachBottom = !recyclerView.canScrollHorizontally(-1);

            //        // vertical
            //        Boolean reachBottom = !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1);

            //        if (reachBottom) {
            //            loadMorePost();
            //        }
            //     }
            // });

            // TRY NEW SCROLL METHOD
            recyclerProfileDashboard.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                    if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                        isScrolling = true;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                   super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);                  

                   currentItems = manager.getChildCount();
                   totalItems = manager.getItemCount();
                   scrollOutItems = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                   if (isScrolling && (currentItems + scrollOutItems == totalItems)) {
                       isScrolling = false;
                       // implement progress bar here
                       loadMorePost();
                   }
               }

            });

            // RETRIEVING SEEN
            Query firstQuery = firebaseFirestore
                    .collection("ProfileDashboard")
                    .document(currentUserId)
                    .collection("ProfileInfo")
                    .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                    .limit(5);

            // Activity.this if not fragment /// Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()),
            firstQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                        // please add if doc not empty
                        if (isFirstPageFirstLoad) {
                            lastVisible = documentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(documentSnapshots.size() - 1); // array 0, 1, 2
                        }

                        for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                            if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                                //String postId = doc.getDocument().getId();
                                contentProfileDashboard = doc.getDocument().toObject(ContentProfileDashboard.class);


                                if (isFirstPageFirstLoad) {
                                    contentListDashboard.add(contentProfileDashboard);
                                } else {
                                    contentListDashboard.add(0, contentProfileDashboard);
                                }

                                // fire the event
                                adapterProfileDashboard.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }

                        isFirstPageFirstLoad = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }


   public void loadMorePost() {

        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

            String currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

            Query nextQuery = firebaseFirestore
                    .collection("ProfileDashboard")
                    .document(currentUserId)
                    .collection("ProfileInfo")
                    .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                    .startAfter(lastVisible)
                    .limit(5);

            nextQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {

                        lastVisible = documentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(documentSnapshots.size() - 1);
                        for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                            if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                                //String postId = doc.getDocument().getId();
                                // contentSeen = doc.getDocument().toObject(ContentProfile.class);
                                // contentList.add(contentSeen);

                                contentProfileDashboard = doc.getDocument().toObject(ContentProfileDashboard.class);
                                contentListDashboard.add(contentProfileDashboard);

                                //adapterSeen.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                adapterProfileDashboard.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
   }
```

This is **Adapter**

```
public class AdapterProfileDashboard extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterProfileDashboard.ViewHolder> {

    public List<ContentProfileDashboard> contentList;
    public Context context;

    public AdapterProfileDashboard(List<ContentProfileDashboard> contentList){
        this.contentList = contentList; 
    }   


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_profile_dashboard, parent, false);
        context = parent.getContext(); // or add in parameter constructor this.context = context; and set in HomeFragment AdapterFragmentHome(container.getContext(), contentList);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

        String text = contentList.get(position).getProfileText();
        holder.setUserText(text);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contentList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private View mView;
        private TextView userProfile;
        //private TextView textDashboard;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

        }

        public void setUserText(String text) {

            userProfile = mView.findViewById(R.id.profile_text_dashboard);
            userProfile.setText(text);
        }

    }

}
```

my question is how to refresh recycle view correctly?.. so my data not lost?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: sory sir, just edited my question is how to refresh recycle view correctly?.. so my data not lost? thank you @AlexMamo